# Can I use DD-WRT and a VPN to access devices on my company network using internal DNS names?

Tags: networking, router, vpn, dns, dd-wrt

I'd like to setup an internal DNS server on my company network to resolve a few internal names (some-server.mycompany, another-server.mycompany, etc.) and I'd also like to be able to access those same devices by name from home via a VPN.

How would a DNS request for some-server.mycompany get resolved if I'm on my home network and connected to the company VPN?

I'm on OSX and I'm wondering if I can achieve this with DD-WRT.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Does it have to be a made-up suffix like `.mycompany`, or can it be a global suffix that you own like `.lan.mycompany.org`? Are you running the VPN connection from the DD-WRT router or from your OSX system?

Comment: @grawity It could be the latter if that's easier but I thought that a local-only suffix might cause less confusion. As for the VPN connection, I'm not sure. It seems like it makes sense to have DD-WRT handle the server part of the VPN and my OSX laptop is just a client? I'm new to VPNs.

Comment: Ah, right, I didn't notice that the DD-WRT is on the company network.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by modifying the dd-wrt dnsmasq config to forward requests to company domain name to the internal company nameservers accessible only through the link.

To do this I used lines

```
  server=/domain.name/ip.add.re.ss
```

Where ip.add.re.ss was an internal company nameserver reachableonly through DNS.

Depending on the coupling of the 2 systems I have in other places used a hosts file as a source of truth for dnsmasq at both locations and pushed this out from a master to slaves - this has the advantage if breaking less if the VPN goes down but there are resources which should be available through the public interface.

Another technique I have used (sparingly) is to create a hard to guess subdomain and make internal hosts subdomains of that. This coukd be refined by hsnding out the donain suffix, but has a whole lot of limitations.